# Horizontal scrollview in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have a list of MyClass:

```
 public class MyClass
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
        }
```

I would like to display this list in a Horizontal scrollview. Im doing it in XAML and having a hard time finding examples. I got this now:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ListView x:Name="MyClassList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassList}"
                    RowHeight="210">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Grid Padding="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name:" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Type:" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Type}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>

          </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
```

But this presents the list in a vertical manner. Any tips on how to scroll this list horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if I understand the issue. My interpretation is that you want the ListView itself to add elements horizontally instead of vertically.

This can be achieved by settings the ListViews ItemsPanel to a horizontal StackPanel.

Try this:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListView x:Name="MyClassList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassList}"
                  RowHeight="210">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name:" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Type:" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Type}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. In this example you suggest that I put my grid inside of the stackpanel? It might be differences between MSXAML and XamarinXAML. It does not work for me but thank you.

Comment: You might be right, I haven't ised XamarinXAML. But you shouldn't place your grid inside the stackpanel, but keep the ItemTemplate as is... I'll update with the complete code, if you want to try it

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatley it does not seem to be legal Xaml in Xamarin.

Comment: Ok, it seems a bit strange, maybe it can be fixed with some adjustments. Hope you find a good solution

Comment: One last thought... does it work with a <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"> instead of the StackPanel? (did some googling on Xamarin XAML)

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved with a custom class called ItemsView (not to be confused with Xamarin's ItemsView for data templating in a ListView) which implements a ScrollView/StackPanel pattern.  Please see the code: https://gist.github.com/fonix232/b88412a976f67315f915